# Search box to search marker (Google Map)

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, search-box

I want to ask about android app that I develop using google map in my apps. I already make multi marker on my map (1323 data so 1323 marker). So the question is:

I want to make search box to find specific marker on my map. I dont know how to find. Is it can find using title or snippet in marker

```
c = myDbHelper.query("Landslide", null, null, null, null,null, null);
if(c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String loc = c.getString(3);
        Double lat = c.getDouble(4);
        Double lng = c.getDouble(5);
        String date = c.getString(1);
        //Integer death = c.getInt(6);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .title(loc + "")
            .snippet("Latitude:" + lat + " " + "Longitude:" + lng + " " + "Date:" + date + "")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red1)));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Thanks In advance who helping me,
regards,
Hafizul Reza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gess your markers data are stored in SQLite on your device. 
You can try to add a search box such as EditText, in your layout xml :

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_textt_d"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then implement then onChange :

```
    yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
    yourEditTextaddTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            changeMarker(s)
        } 
 });
```

On each change you should :
delete the current marker of your map, 
query only markers that match the search box value :

```
public void changeMarker(String searchString) {
    ...
    myGoogleMap.clear();
    c=myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM marker WHERE marker.name LIKE '"+searchString+"%'");
    ...
}
```

And then add your marker back on the map as you did in your question. Hope this help...

Comment: Dear Lary,  I so confuse where to put onchange and what is "youredittext". Thanks for your reply sir. here my full code http://pastebin.com/qG3rJKtm. im so confuse. can you guide me sir . Thanks ;)

Comment: Hey,sorry for the late answer. you can put the onchange in  `onCreate(){...` of your `MapsActivity` and the `<EditText .. >` in th xml of the file R.layout.activity_maps.

Comment: This error come out..  The value myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM marker WHERE marker.name LIKE '"+searchString+"%'") assigned to 'c' is never used less...
This inspection points out the cases where a variable value is never used after its assignment, i.e.:  - the variable never gets read after assignment OR  - the value is always overwritten with another assignment before the next variable read OR  - the variable initializer is redundant (for one of the above two reasons) OR  - the variable is never used.

Comment: my code sir. I really need your help. http://pastebin.com/mD84cJgA . can you check my coding. is it correct or not. I follow your step sir. I already comment which line error. Thanks btw Lary. I appreciate you work hard to help me

Answer (score 1):

Create global List/Map/Array of your Markers:

```
private HashMap<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap<String,Marker>();
```

---

And fill it by Markers:

```
//...
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .title(loc + "")
            .snippet("Latitude:" + lat + " " + "Longitude:" + lng + " " + "Date:" + date + "")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.red1)));
markers.put("Name1", marker);
//add more and more markers
```

---

Now you can easily find and get any marker:

```
Marker marker = markers.get("Name1");
```

---

As a first parameter of markers HashMap you can put Marker title/snippet/coordinates/... .